# About the probability of satisfying in a commutator type equation

Tags: gr.group-theory, harmonic-analysis, haar-measure

Let $N$ be a closed normal subgroup of a compact group $G$. We denote the unique Haar measure of a compact group $A$ by $\mathbf m_A$, and drop $A$ if there exists no ambiguity. Fix $y\in G$. For $g\in G$, define
$$s(g):=\mathbf m(\{(\xi,\eta)\in N\times N: [\xi g,y,\eta]=1\})$$
Do we have $\max\{s(g): g\in G\}=s(1)$?

(**Def**: For group elements $x,y\,\text{and}\,z$, $[x,y]:=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ and $[x,y,z]:=[[x,y],z]$.)

Comment: There's a trivial partial answer, if I'm not mistaken: if $G, N$ are algebraic, then $[\zeta g, y, \eta] = 1$ is an algebraic equation, so the space of solutions is a subvariety. If $N$ is connected, then any subvariety of $N \times N$ is either the entire space or a subvariety of codimension at least $1$, and therefore should have measure 0.